# How to prove $f^{-1}(f(A))=A \quad \Longrightarrow f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap B$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

$X,Y$ are Quantites and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a function that is injective.

i have already proven that $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$ when $f$ is injective.

How to prove $f^{-1}(f(A))=A \quad \Longrightarrow f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap B$?

Comment: Perhaps you mean $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$.

Comment: Even with @RobertIsrael 's correction, I'm not convinced this is a true statement. Also, $X,Y$ are sets, not quantities.

Comment: Hello Don Thousand, i have to show the equivalence of five statements. And I thought that i'd proof the equivalence like this:    a => b => c => d => e => a

Comment: Maybe this is worth reading: [$f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$ $\iff$ $f$ is injective.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138286/fa-cap-b-fa-cap-fb-iff-f-is-injective)

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth This is probably what OP meant. I would close as a duplicate of that problem

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3198722/showing-equivalences-functions-injective

Comment: Do you have that $f^{-1}(A\cap B)=f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$ ?

Comment: No. I have not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$
when f is injective.  So what?  Prove that
if for all A, $f^{-1}(f(A))=A,$
then f is injective.
Now use the injectiveness of f to show the desired conclusion for all A and B.

The use of variables in your question was disastrous for not being properly quantified.